# Ubuntu/Debian install nginx-extras

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, debian

I have maybe a stupid question but I just want to be sure that my thoughts are correct. I have Ubuntu 12.04 server. Also I have nginx installed on the server. Now I want to install nginx-extras. So the question is: Will nginx-extras override old nginx installation and I should change all the settings again or not?

Thanks,
Igor

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! [This site is intended as a programming Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). For questions like this about server configuration, you might want to head over to http://SuperUser.com. Or, since your question may be specific to Ubuntu, http://AskUbuntu.com/ could also be a good place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this will just install additional packages, without any harm to already installed.

You can easyli check any package at packages.debian.org

So, for nginx-extras this will be
https://packages.debian.org/sid/nginx-extras

You can see there are dep packages - ngin-extras's dependiences. They'll be installed if are not present already in your system. If any exists already and have a correct version - it will be ignored. If version is too low, package will be upgraded, but config files will remain unchanged.

Only way the package can change your config files is when it's own config file is replaced in upgrade. But there will be a prompt and you can choose to change, don't change, watch diff etc.